# Inexplicable Urllib2 problem between virtualenv's. 

Tags: python, http, cookies, urllib2, mechanize

I have some test code (as a part of a webapp) that uses urllib2 to perform an operation I would usually perform via a browser:

- Log in to a remote website
- Move to another page
- Perform a POST by filling in a form

I've created 4 separate, clean virtualenvs (with --no-site-packages) on 3 different machines, all with different versions of python but the exact same packages (via pip requirements file), and the code only works on the two virtualenvs on my local development machine(2.6.1 and 2.7.2) - it won't work on either of my production VPSs

In the failing cases, I can log in successfully, move to the correct page but when I submit the form, the remote server replies telling me that there has been an error - it's an application server error page ('we couldn't complete your request') and not a webserver error.

- because I can successfully log in and maneuver to a second page, this doesn't seem to be a session or a cookie problem - it's particular to the final POST
- because I can perform the operation on a particular machine with the EXACT same headers and data, this doesn't seem to be a problem with what I am requesting/posting
- because I am trying the code on two separate VPS rented from different companies, this doesn't seem to be a problem with the VPS physical environment
- because the code works on 2 different python versions, I can't imagine it being an incompabilty problem

I'm completely lost at this stage as to why this wouldn't work. I've even 'turned-it-off-and-turn-it-on-again' because I just can't see what the problem could be.

I think it has to be something to do with the final POST coming from a VPS that the remote server doesn't like, but I can't figure out what that could be. I feel like there is something going on under the hood of URLlib that is causing the remote server to dislike the reply.

**EDIT**
I've installed the exact same Python version (2.6.1) on the VPS as is on my working local copy and it doesn't work remotely, so it must be something to do with originating from a VPS. How could this effect the Http request? Is it something lower level?

Comment: Are there any firewalls running on the VPS or on the target website?  Are you using cookies, and if so, are they being written properly in production?

Comment: No, I'm running it on two separate VPSs and it doesn't work for either, but I don't think they are behind firewalls. I am using cookies with cookielib, but I don't think that's the problem because the cookies work for the first two operations (login and change page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I know *why* the problem was happening, but I'm not 100% the reason for it.

I simply had to make the server wait (time.sleep()) after it sent the 2nd request (*Move to another page*) before doing the 3rd request (*Perform a POST by filling in a form*).

I don't know is it because of a condition with the 3rd party server, or if it's some sort of odd issue with URLlib? The reason it seemed to work on my development machine is presumably because it was slower then the server at running the code?

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting the debuglevel=1 for urllib2 and see what it comes up with:

```
import urllib2
h=urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(h)
...
```

Comment: I've been through the them with a fine tooth comb! I've also compared the working ones to the non-working ones and they are fairly identical. I'll edit and put up some examples

Answer (score 1):

This is a total shot in the dark, but are your VPSs 64-bit and your home computer 32-bit, or vice versa?  Maybe a difference in default sizes or accuracies of *something* could be freaking out the server.

Barring that, can you try to find out any information on the software stack the web server is using?

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately they are the same!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with urllib2 (working with Zimbra's REST api), in the end switched to pycurl with success.

PS
for operations of login/navigate/post, I usually find [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) useful and easier to use. Maybe you can give it a show.

Comment: I think this might be the only option at this stage. I've tried everything conceivable to get it to work and I can only imagine it's a  obscure compatibility issue. I was actually using Mechanize which is excellent, but unfortunately I believe it sits on top of Urllib2 which means the same problem occurs.